# Does this design cause floating input?

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, logic-gates, pullup

I started investigating this circuit. The circuit is used to detect another PCBA when it is plugged in as the signal IN# and sends the signal IN#_BUF to the microcontroller.

The issue is sometimes the output from NC7WZ04 pin 4 is 1.2V, whereas it is expected to be around 3.3V. This signal goes directly to a GPIO, which is set to input. It's not likely caused by other components because I have measured and confirmed all points in this circuit.

Will this cause a floating signal in pin 4? But this circuit is already pulled-up at pin 1, so I'm not really sure.

And also while measuring the voltage at pin 4 after removing the daughter board, the signal at pin 4 increases to 3.3V. Could the internal resistance of the multimeter have contributed to this behavior?

Here's what I have measured using a faulty PCBA:
Pin 1: 3.3V
Pin 3: 0V
Pin 4: 1.2V (expected 3.3V)
Pin 5: 3.3V
Pin 6: 0V

And this design has been in use for more than 7 years, and this issue has just appeared.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the soldering joints?

Comment: How are the LEDs connected? Output sourcing or sinking?

Comment: I already checked the soldering joint and it's ok

Comment: Welcome! Please include the actual LEDs in your schematic.

Comment: In case you are using either the SIP or the UDF package I'd suspect soldering as well. Try to heat up the joints with a hot air soldering station, if you have access to one.

Comment: "...detect another PCBA": Is this the daughter board? "Here's what I have measured using a faulty PCBA":daughter board or mother board? Is the daughter board inserted or not when making the measurements? Where is the microcontroller?daughter board or mother board?. Please edit the question to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

The inverter has push-pull output.

If supply voltage and voltage on input pin 3 are stable, the output on pin 4 should also be stable.

Either the inverter is faulty or the circuit after it.

If pin 3 is 0V, the pin 4 should be 3.3V, and if pin 3 is 3.3V, pin 4 should be 0V.